# Determine whether account exists

Tags: powershell, office365

In my powershell script I need to determine whether an account exists, and I want to construct a single function to return a boolean.

Here is my current function - problem with this is that I need to know before-hand what type of account it is.  You can't run `get-mailuser` against a licensed account, and you can't run `get-mailbox` against a Mail-User or Mail-Contact object.  I understand it is because these are two different modules interacting with two different object-sets.

So how can I fix this function so that I can just test for the existence of the account without knowing what kind of account it is?

```
#test for existing account
function accountexists($whatusertype, $whatusername){
    $itexists = $false
    switch($usertype){  #you can't use get-mailbox for mail-users or mail-contacts
        ("mail-user"){$itexists = [bool](get-mailuser -identity $whatusername -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) }
        ("mail-contact"){ $itexists = [bool](get-mailuser -identity $whatusername -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)}
        ("licensed"){ $itexists = [bool](get-mailbox -identity $whatusername -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) }
    }
    return $itexists
}
```

Or maybe the title to this question should be `How to determine account type?`

Comment: What about using Get-AdObject?  technically if there is a chance that a PC or group exists with the name it might give a false positive but if your naming convention differs for users and groups this shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @MikeGaruccio : Mail-user won't be part of an Ad object. It just sits on the  Exchange Server only. But yes, you can pull other users' object except few cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So basically you should check the recipient I believe.

> Get-Recipient -Identity user01@mydomain.com

will return the recipient object.

You can use **-ANR** to search using Ambiguous Name Resolution

> Get-Recipient -ANR user01

**Note**: ANR can return multiple matches and it won't give the SMTP alias matches.

Comment: Perfect!  Just what I wanted.

Comment: @bgmCoder: Please Accept the answer also. :)

Comment: Maybe help me with this one, too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41228557/how-to-determine-account-type

Comment: Let me check and I will reply over there.