# How to Determine Account Type?

Tags: powershell, office365

In my script I need to know whether an account is a `Mail-User`, `Mail-Contact` or licensed user account.

Presently I have to know this before-hand and supply it to the script myself.

Is there a better way than this?  This only figures between a licensed user and a Mail-Contact-or-Mail-User.

```
#test for existing account
function GetAccountType($whatusername){

    $isType = [bool](get-mailbox -identity $whatusername -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
    if($isType){
        $thisType = "Licensed"
    }else{
        $isType = [bool](get-mailuser -identity $whatusername -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
        if($isType){
            $thisType = "Mail-Contact"
        }
    }

    return $thisType
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **RecipientTypeDetails** specifies the type of recipients returned.

You can select from the following values with **Get-Recipient**:

1. ArbitrationMailbox
2. ConferenceRoomMailbox
3. Contact
4. DiscoveryMailbox
5. DynamicDistributionGroup
6. EquipmentMailbox
7. ExternalManagedContact
8. ExternalManagedDistributionGroup
9. LegacyMailbox
10. LinkedMailbox
11. MailboxPlan
12. MailContact
13. MailForestContact
14. MailNonUniversalGroup
15. MailUniversalDistributionGroup
16. MailUniversalSecurityGroup
17. MailUser
18. PublicFolder
19. RoleGroup
20. RoomList
21. RoomMailbox
22. SharedMailbox
23. SystemAttendantMailbox
24. SystemMailbox
25. User
26. UserMailbox

What I am understanding from your case is that you need **UserMailbox**, **User** , **MailUser** , **MailContact**

I don't have an exchange setup right now. BUt you can set off with these value.
It falls under *Microsoft.Exchange.Data.Directory.Recipient.RecipientTypeDetails[]*

Comment: This is perfect - one line of code gets it all - perfect.

Comment: This even gets SharedMailbox

Comment: Yes. It does.. I think now you can write the condition based on that. Else I will sit on it, but  I need to setup environment first for this case. :)

Comment: It does - I tried it.  This is wonderful.  Thanks for answering.

Comment: Happy to help you out @bgmCoder :)

Comment: Now I want to find out what kind of group I have: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41336598/how-to-determine-group-type  Maybe you have some ideas for this, too?

Answer (score 2):

I would probably look at `RecipientTypeDetails` to get the Mailbox type for the Mailbox/MailContact.

Maybe do the opposite if you have more MailContacts then Mailboxes in order to optimze it.

And I guess by "Licensed" you mean a UserMailbox? Since you do not mention Azure AD. In Azure AD you have `IsLicensed` with `Get-MsolUser`.

```
function GetAccountType($user)
{
    $Mailbox = Get-Mailbox -identity $user | select name, RecipientTypeDetails
    $type = ""
    if ($Mailbox.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "UserMailbox")
    {
        $type = "Licensed"
    }
    elseif ($Mailbox.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "SharedMailbox")
    {
        $type = "Shared"
    }
    else
    {
        $MailUser = Get-MailContact -identity $user | select name, RecipientTypeDetails
        if ($MailUser.RecipientTypeDetails -eq "MailContact")
        {
            $type = "Mail-Contact"
        }
        else
        {
            $type = "Something else"
        }
    }
    $type
}

$a = GetAccountType -user "userid"
$a | Out-Host
```

Comment: @bgmCoder, Done. Same thing should work for MailContacts.

Comment: Also, `RecipientType` returns `UserMailbox` for both a LIcensed User AND a SharedMailbox - it doesn't differentiate.  I just tested it.  But discovering whether it is a shared mailbox would make the function perfect.

Comment: @dgmCoder, ah ok. How about `RecipientTypeDetails`. Should be different based on my O365 environment.

Comment: Sorry - yes, sorry, we are using Office365 online with Azure.

Comment: Ah!  You nailed it with RecipientTypeDetails - that's it!

Comment: You have one update left to make for your function to be correct (in case anyone else comes along): you have to test using `get-mailuser` AND `get-mailcontact` for each one, respectfully.  Here is what I came up with based on your answer: http://p.ahkscript.org/?p=ca35955d